# Final Project - Android App Communicate With C#/ASP.Net WebService

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json, web-services

Actually my question is bigger than this. I have an idea for my final project, I want to create an application that gathered all news from different news websites in one place, but I want to create it in different languages. I want a website by ASP.NET/C# and an Android Application, but I want to make my ASP.NET/C# side like a robot; crawl all news websites and save articles in a SQL Server Database. I want to display it with HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript. I may want to make an android app (using java) to communicate with this webservice and get prepared text in JSON Format, it's roll just display!! 
Project Guidelines :

- Creating WebService by C# saves articles in Database and output it by JSON
- WebSite by ASP.NET connect to SQL Server and get news directly
- Android App get the news in JSON format from C# WebService

as you can see, i will use alot of languages [JAVA, C#, ASP.NET, HTML5, CSS3, JAVASCRIPT]

My question is: is this even POSSIBLE?
Is it too much for a 2 year final project?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible. This kind of thing happens on the web every single day.

As to whether it is possible in two years, I would say that depends a lot on your scope, your personal skill level, and the time and resources available to you. If it were me I might try to shoot for just the web service and the Android app to start, as that will give you a fully working system you can demonstrate, and if your goal is to learn many technologies, you won't learn that many new things from building the web site that you didn't learn from the building the service.

I would highly suggest you look into using [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for your service, as the RESTful service architecture lends itself cleanly to platform-agnostic (Android, in your case) communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using json data. In your android app collect whatever data say for e.g. user profile like name, email, phone, address. Create an object and store into this. Then serialize and post it to an aspx page. In aspx page deserialize the data, process it and then push the response back to android app.

A nice article describes this entire process here
http://www.youritbuddy.com/blog/post/2016/11/14/json-communication-between-android-and-asp-net-c